# How can I have one function run only when the other has finished ? (setTimeout within for-loop)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await, resolve

I've trying to find an easy, straightforward way to get the second function to run after the first one finishes. I've tried some suggestions I've come across online but these particular functions seem to operate differently due to the fact that they have setTimeouts within for-loops. Everything I've tried so far causes the second function to run before the first one is finished doing its thing (which is to update some color styling on the page).

```
const [VisitedNodes, setVisitedNodes] = useState([]);  
const [ShortestPath, setShortestPath] = useState([]);

// runs first
function drawVisitedNodes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < VisitedNodes.length; i++) {
    const node = VisitedNodes[i];
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(`${node.x}-${node.y}`).className =
          "node-visited";
    }, i);
  }
  drawShortestPath();
}

// runs second
function drawShortestPath() {
  for (let i = 0; i < ShortestPath.length; i++) {
    const node = ShortestPath[i];
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(`${node.x}-${node.y}`).className =
          "node-shortPath";

    }, i * 10);
  }
}

<button 
    onClick={drawVisitedNodes}>Visualize
</button>
```

Comment: Promisify the setTimeout, and await inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
const [VisitedNodes, setVisitedNodes] = useState([]);  
const [ShortestPath, setShortestPath] = useState([]);

// runs first
function drawVisitedNodes() {
  let x= 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < VisitedNodes.length; i++) {
    const node = VisitedNodes[i];
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(`${node.x}-${node.y}`).className =
          "node-visited";
    }, i);
    x++;
  }
  setTimeout(() =>  drawShortestPath(), x);
}

// runs second
function drawShortestPath() {
  for (let i = 0; i < ShortestPath.length; i++) {
    const node = ShortestPath[i];
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(`${node.x}-${node.y}`).className =
          "node-shortPath";

    }, i * 10);
  }
}

<button 
    onClick={drawVisitedNodes}>Visualize
</button>
```

This will add some delay to the execution of the second function. How much time? The `x` will tell you, because at the end of the `for` it will be `VisitedNodes.length`. Yes, you can also do it like this:

```
setTimeout(() =>  drawShortestPath(), VisitedNodes.length)
```

So, just to give you an idea of why this works, I’m gonna give you the next example:

- `VisitedNodes` state is an array of 4 elements.
- `ShortestPath` state is an array of 2 elements.
- Click on the button will cause the execution of the `drawVisitedNodes()` function.

**In your case, the execution will be:**

1. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode1, 0)`
2. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode2, 1)`
3. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode3, 2)`
4. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode4, 3)`
5. `drawShortestPath()`

But, because of the setTimeout’s, the actual execution will be:

1. `drawShortestPath()`
2. `codeForNode1`
3. `codeForNode2`
4. `codeForNode3`
5. `codeForNode4`

**With what I recommend you, your code will keep the order. Let’s see:**

1. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode1, 0)`
2. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode2, 1)`
3. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode3, 2)`
4. `setTimeout(() => codeForNode4, 3)`
5. `setTimeout(() => drawShortestPath(), 4)`

The final execution will be:

1. `codeForNode1`
2. `codeForNode2`
3. `codeForNode3`
4. `codeForNode4`
5. `drawShortestPath()`

---

In the comments, you asked me why using an actual number doesn’t work. Well, my answer is that it depends on the amount of `VisitedNodes` that you have. Using the example I just gave you, if you use `x < 4` it won’t work, because you are trying to execute the `drawShortestPath()` function before `codeForNode4` gets executed, so you are mixing the executions in that case. But if you set an `x ≥ 4` it will work as you expect.

Comment: Hey it worked! Could you provide a brief explanation as to how adding a simple x++ counter as the setTimeout delay caused it to work? How come having the setTimeout inside the for-loop makes it act to strange? No async or awaits seem to work here. Thanks

Comment: Hey! Nice to hear that! Yes sure. What you have to think is that code is sequentially executed. So when you call `drawVisitedNodes` you start with a `for` loop and for each iteration you are doing a `setTimeout`, so you are postponing a code execution (the one inside the setTimeout) for an X amount time (in this case, for each visitedNode, by 0,1,2,3…), but that doesn't mean that the code can't keep running. So, after the `for` loop finishes, which will be really fast, it won’t give time to execute the code inside the setTimeout’s that were executed before, soo…

Comment: ... the next instruction to execute will be the call to the second function. So as all of this happens really fast, my recommendation was to add a delay to execute the second function. For how much time? The `x` will tell you, because at the end of the `for` it will be `VisitedNodes.length + 1`. Yes, for this case, you can also do it like this: `setTimeout(() =>  drawShortestPath(), VisitedNodes.length + 1);`, I've just realised while writing you. I will update my answer later.

Comment: Using VisitedNodes.length works well but how come using the actual number(as opposed to the variable: VisitedNodes.length or 'x') wont do it? It doesn't seem to work when I use a number itself as the delay for the setTimeout. Strange?

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Check it out and ask me if you have any questions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `await` to wait till all the logic done

***like this***

```
async function foo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < VisitedNodes.length; i++) {
        const node = VisitedNodes[i];
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById(`${node.x}-${node.y}`).className =
              "node-visited";
        }, i);
    }
}

function drawVisitedNodes() {
  await foo();
  drawShortestPath();
}

// runs second
function drawShortestPath() {
  for (let i = 0; i < ShortestPath.length; i++) {
    const node = ShortestPath[i];
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(`${node.x}-${node.y}`).className =
          "node-shortPath";

    }, i * 10);
  }
}
```